# Auditing device files using auditcl daemon

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, tty, auditing

I am trying to see what commands are typed in my terminal and serial port. For that I am using auditd daemon which helps me in auditing files.

I thought of a creating audit rules on /dev/tty and /dev/ttyAMA0 for seeing whats happening on terminal and serial device respectively.

`auditctl -w /dev/tty -p rwx -k terminal`

`auditctl -w /dev/ttyAMA0 -p rwx -k serialport`

But this records only the echo on tty. I cant audit all the commands typed on the terminal. I enabled tty logging in the PAM file too by adding `session required pam_tty_audit.so enable=*` in /etc/pam.d/sshd file.

Is there any other way to do this auditing. I want to use auditd daemon only so that all my auditing log is in one file.

Comment: I did this by `auditctl -a exit,always -F euid=0 -S execve`  but it logs all the system calls. Is there anyway to filter it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auditctl -a exit,always -S execve` did the job for me. But it creates too many logs so figuring how to remove the logs created by background process